# Sorting some pattern matching lines based on hex on a file

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed, hex

I have a file called `stuff.txt` containing this:

```
#Some text
##More text
blahblahblah
TAG["1AF450"]
TAG["002B4C"]
TAG["FFF250"]
TAG["6D50BB"]
more text...
#blehblehbleh
```

I want to order in the file only the lines containing the `TAG` based on their hex value. Desired output:

```
#Some text
##More text
blahblahblah
TAG["002B4C"]
TAG["1AF450"]
TAG["6D50BB"]
TAG["FFF250"]
more text...
#blehblehbleh
```

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: are all tags 6 exactly characters long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^TAG/{print | "sort"; next} 1' file

#Some text
##More text
blahblahblah
TAG["002B4C"]
TAG["1AF450"]
TAG["6D50BB"]
TAG["FFF250"]
more text...
#blehblehbleh
```

**NB.** since your records have fixed structure no need to extract the hex values since lexical sorting of the lines will have the same sorting order.

Comment: yeah, this might be `awk` version specific.  Works for `GNU Awk 4.1.4`

Comment: It's not just awk version specific, it's undefined behavior and what it outputs will  depend on awk, shell, etc.versions and the size of the input as that'll determine when sort produces output and the sort version, buffering used, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that hex numbers are always 6 uppercase characters long.

With GNU awk:

```
awk '/^TAG\["[[:xdigit:]]{6}"]$/ { a[i++]=$0; next }
     a[0] {
         asort(a);
         for (j=1;j<=i;j++) { print a[j] }
         delete a;
         i=0
     }1' file
```

Notice: If the file eventually ends with several TAG records, you have to add at the end of the script:

```
END{
    asort(a);
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++) { print a[j] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'if (/TAG\[".*"\]/){
              push @t, $_;
          } elsif (@t) {
              print for map qq(TAG["$_"]\n),
                        sort { hex $a <=> hex $b }
                        map /(?<=").+(?=")/g, @t;
              @t = ();
              print;
          } else { print }' -- stuff.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- if the line matches the regular expression, i.e. it contains TAG["..."], it's pushed to the array @t
- otherwise, if @t has already been populated, it's sorted by the hex value and printed; @t is emptied so it won't be printed again
- otherwise, we are before the first TAG or we've already printed it, so we print the line.

If the hex values are all of the same length (with 0's at the beginning for small numbers), you can simplify the sorting to

```
print for sort @t;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU csplit, sort & bash):

```
csplit file '/^TAG/' '/^[^T]/' && cat xx00 <(sort xx01) xx02 > file && rm xx??
```

Split the file into 3 parts, concatenate the head, the sorted middle and the tail back to the original and remove any working files created by csplit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your tags are the same length, this is how to do the job robustly:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '!(/^TAG/ && p~/^TAG/){c++} {print c, $0; p=$0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -f2-
#Some text
##More text
blahblahblah
TAG["002B4C"]
TAG["1AF450"]
TAG["6D50BB"]
TAG["FFF250"]
more text...
#blehblehbleh
```